# How to return the max value between 3 values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, overloading, initializer-list

I am trying to return the max value using the **max** function but its not working on 3 values.

**CodeBlocks Error:**

> error: '__comp' cannot be used as a function

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << max(5, 10, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this overloaded function `std::max` that accepts an object of the type `std::initializer_list<int>`:

```
cout << max( { 5, 10, 20 } );
```

This function has the following declaration

```
template<class T>
constexpr T max(initializer_list<T> t);
```

Otherwise the compiler tries to select the function

```
template<class T, class Compare>
constexpr const T& max(const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp);
```

and issues an error.

Pay attention to that you need to include the header `<algorithm>`,

Comment: I noticed that it also worked for  cout << min( { 5, 10, 20 } );